# How to find if string contains a specific word in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one column with comma separeted strings and a several with words that can be in these strings. I have to find if a a word from a column name is in a string. I used a regexmatch formula, but it doesn't distinguisch TV from TV remote. How can I fix this?

Mu formula:
arrayformula(if(L1<>"";if(REGEXMATCH($K$2:$K;L$1)=TRUE;"Wybrano";"");""))

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSduv.png)

Or if it will be simplier I have to count how many times the certain word occured in the column with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(K2:INDEX(K2:K;ROW(LOOKUP("ZZZ";K:K))));COUNTA(L1:1);LAMBDA(r;c;IF(LEN(INDEX(K2:K;r));IF(REGEXMATCH(INDEX(K2:K;r);INDEX(L1:1;;c)&"(?:,|$)");"Wybrano";);)))
```

- Adjust the column range here `COUNTA(L1:1)` to something like `COUNTA(L1:P1)` or so depending on your dataset.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFNA(BYCOL(L1:P1, LAMBDA(y, BYROW(K2:K, LAMBDA(x, 
 IF(MATCH("*"&y&"*", x, ), "Wybrano"))))))
```

[image]